# XML RPC client for C# over secured socket (https)

Tags: c#, python, https, xml-rpc

I have a secured (https) XML-RPC server written in python, and I have tested it with a python based client. but I need a C# based client for it, I have given a try to [xml-rpc.net](http://www.xml-rpc.net)

but it is not working with https? can any one please help me out? or I will have to write a client from scratch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your https server probably has a self-signed or other invalid certificate. Get a valid certificate or suppress https certificate validation with

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, e) => true ;
```

Comment: Thanks Anton for your help. Please will you eleborate what the above line of code is doing? as I can't understand the syntaxt (a, b, c, e) => true;

Comment: `(a, b, c, e) => true` is C# 3.5+ lambda syntax, shorthand for an anonymous method taking four arguments (look up `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in MSDN) and returning `true` to unconditionally accept the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I am able to call from .NET enviornment. but the problem is How can use the xml-rpc.NET library in silverlight project? as I can't include the reference in my project.

Comment: I don't know about Silverlight, can only advise you to recompile XmlRpc library from source targeting Silverlight.